# Cannot access variable inside event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to handle a basic form(using JQuery for DOM).

Here is my code:

```
var username = $('#username').val();
var email = $('#email').val();
var pass = $('#pass').val();

$('#signup').on('click', function() {
    alert(username);
});
```

I checked and top three variables work as expected before the event is triggered. Inside the function, `alert(username)` is giving an empty string.

Please help!!!

Comment: Most likely because you are setting the variable values when the page loads and the inputs are empty. You need to read the *inside the event handler, after the user has typed a value in to them*

Comment: In the second version, the argument to the event handler is the `Event` object. Calling it `username` doesn't make it access the global variable.

Comment: probably you  are assigning an empty string to `username` (you might want to get the value inside the event listener function, not before it)... for the second snipped, that `username` parameter has nothing to do with the original `username` (if not the same name)

Comment: Yes, I am clicking the button after typing a value. Also, variables are being set as it gives expected output when used outside event function.

Comment: Exactly. Did you read my previous comment?

Comment: Oh, I got it, can you post an answer so that I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's because you make `username` event object inside the click event when you handle event it's back an object so here's you make `username` is the event object inside this function so it's won't refer to the first value anymore it's will take the new value of the event object so just remove `username` from the parentheses

```js
$('#signup').on('click', function() {
  var username = $('#username').val();
  var email = $('#email').val();
  var pass = $('#pass').val();
  alert(username);
});
```

It should work now

Comment: It gives empty string :(

Comment: Ok i forgot to add them inside the event just like you i edited it

Comment: Yeah, another person helped me figure it out.

Comment: The description of the solution and the code bear no resemblance to each other. This answer doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I edited my question to make it more specific, it would make sense otherwise.